# Unknown Spatial Reference after Georeferencing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference an image base on another *.tif, after rectifying i still have my Image as unknown spatial reference.

Does somebody know how I can fix it?

Comment: @Martin - That's a legit answer. Please make this comment an answer.

Comment: So, found it. Define projection is in Arctoolbox.

Answer (score 5):

Georeferencing is a process where you define which coordinates your image covers. It'll write in the coordinate system of the data frame. Therefore, it does *not* specify which coordinate system you use, only which coordinates it covers.

The tool [Define projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) (under Data Management --> Projections and transformations) can be used on both vector and raster files to specify the coordinate system it is already in.